# Как передать коллекцию Map в другой Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Как получить доступ к `Map` из другого `Activity`.
Нужны куки для запросов из другого `Activity` при использовании `Jsoup.connect`.
Пробовал использовать `Intent.putExtra`, но объекты типа `Map` не получается передавать, сериализация не срабатывает. Что я делаю не так?

Приведите, пожалуйста короткий наглядный пример кода из 2-х Activity.

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("").data("", "").method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
Map<String, String> Cookies = res.cookies();
```

Comment: `Map` это интерфейс, а не класс, его нельзя сериализовать. Вам надо использовать какую то реализацию интерфейса, например `HashMap` - он сериализуется и передается через интент. В общем то вы не можете получить в этот интерфейс и свои куки тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Сделать Map переменную `public static` и напрямую обращаться к ней из другой активити (`B.Cookies...`). Изначально решение предложено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566921/androidpassing-a-hash-map-between-activities)
2. Использовать Bundle-обертку для передачи объекта: https://gist.github.com/mmarcon/6660453